# numerical solution of partial differential equations by the finite element method claes johnson p

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-element-method

Let us now consider the following abstract minimization problem (M): Find $u \in V$ $$F(u)=min_{v \in V} F(v)$$
    where $$F(v)=\frac{1}{2} a(v,v)- L(v),$$
    and consider also the following abstract variatonal problem (V): Find $u \in V$  $$a(u,v)=L(v) \forall v \in V.$$
Theorem 2.1 The problems (M) and (V) arc equivalent, ie, $u\in V$ satisfies
(M) if and only if u satisfies (V).

Can u help me with the proof of this?(with the reverse implicity,(V)-->(M))

Answer (score 0):

Use
$$
F(u+h)=\frac12 a(u,u)+a(u,h)+\frac12a(h,h)-L(u)-L(h)=\frac12a(h,h)+F(u)
$$
$F(u)$ is a constant and $a(h,h)$ is non-negative...

Comment: can u write me please the whole proof?it ll be very helpful for me.